# Setting minuimum number of reducer for Pig job

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, reducers

I want to set the minimum number of reducer to be launched for my Pig Job.
I tried using the:
        SET default_parallel 57;

But, this forces all jobs to have 57 reducer.

Is there any setting which i can set that forces Pig Job to have minimum 57 or higher number of reducer.

Comment: I tried using SET mapred.reduce.tasks 57; but didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible.

What you could do is setting `default_parallel` to 57 and for those operations that you want to have a higher number of reducers, you could specify a higher number using `PARALLEL`. I understand that this is not exactly what you want though.

Comment: Thanks.I end up doing that only. I found that Pig sends 1 GB of data per reducer by default. The pig.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer setting controls the size of data per reducer. I used this setting to set to 125MB hence i was able to dynamically adjust the number of reducers.